# Pass bridged Swift type into a generic function expecting AnyObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, generics

I have an Objective-C method that expects a class:

```c
@interface A: NSObject

+ (id)produceSomethingOfClass:(Class)cls;

@end
```

My current code to call this from Swift goes like this:

```swift
A.produceSomething(of: X.self) as? X
```

I want to call this logic from Swift, but also *make use of generics*:

```swift
extension A {
    // T needs to conform to `AnyObject` or the compilation will fail because
    // the Objective-C version is expecting a `Class`
    func typedProduceSomething<T: AnyObject>(of cls: T.Type) -> T? {
        return A.produceSomething(of: T.self) as? T
    }
}
```

For `T` conforming to `NSObject`, this works fine:

```swift
class SomeNSObject: NSObject {}
// No compile error
let someInstance = A.typedProduceSomething(of: SomeNSObject.self)
```

However, if I were to call the generic method with a value-semantic type, it fails, even if the type can be bridged to Objective-C:

```swift
// Compile error
A.typedProduceSomething(of: String.self)
```

If I call it with the bridged type then the return value is an optional, so I can't convert it back:

```swift
// Compile error, can't convert NSString? to String?
let someInstance: String? = A.typedProduceSomething(of: NSString.self)
// Old method still works
let someInstance: String = A.produceSomething(of: NSString.self) as? String
```

Is there any way to get `typedProduceSomething` to work with value types bridged to Objective-C?

Comment: `A.typedProduceSomething(of: NSString.self) as? String`  ?

Comment: That defeats the purpose of generics then, since I still have to do the cast outside the function call